# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement vb2008

Tags: sql, database

i got error while inserting new record in database. any help please
error is "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."
ok i add the complete syntax.

```
Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand
        Dim DBConn As OleDbConnection
        Dim DBInsert As New OleDbCommand()
        myword = "عابد"
        mypronounce = "عابِد [عا + بِد]"
        mylanguage = "(عربی)"
        mysiga = "(  مذکر - واحد  )"
        mymuradifat = "زاہِد, پُجاری, مُتَّقی, پارْسا, نیک, صالِح, تَپَسّی, ذاکِر, سَنْت, صُوفی, خُدا پَرَسْت"
        myenglish = "An adorer, worshipper, votary, devotee "
        mymurakbat = "لَکھْنَوی دَبِسْتان,  لَکھْنَوی سِکُول"
        myword = Replace(myword, "'", "''")
        mypronounce = Replace(mypronounce, "'", "''")
        mylanguage = Replace(mylanguage, "'", "''")
        mysiga = Replace(mysiga, "'", "''")
        mymuradifat = Replace(mymuradifat, "'", "''")
        myenglish = Replace(myenglish, "'", "''")
        mymurakbat = Replace(mymurakbat, "'", "''")
        '  & "(word,pronounce,language,siga,mutradifat,english,murakabat) " _
        DBConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & mypath & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxxx;")
        DBInsert.CommandText = "Insert Into data " _
             & "(word,pronounce,language,siga,mufradat,english,murakabat) " _
             & "Values (" _
             & "'" & myword & "', " _
             & "'" & mypronounce & "', " _
             & "'" & mylanguage & "', " _
             & "'" & mysiga & "', " _
             & "'" & mymuradifat & "', " _
             & "'" & myenglish & "', " _
             & "'" & mymurakbat & "')"
        DBInsert.Connection = DBConn
        DBInsert.Connection.Open()
        DBInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        DBConn.Close()
```

Comment: Yes, this is really old school code and subject to sql injection attacks

Comment: Need to see the error message please.

Comment: Seriously - you should **ALWAYS** use parametrized queries - everybody should know that by now, I would think! [Check out this great comic strip](http://xkcd.com/327/) and [read more about parametrized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like you would be wide open to a SQL Injection, and should use parameterized queries.  That in itself would probably resolve it for you.

However, as it stands, its probably due to one or more of the fields you have may have an embedded single quote, thus cancelling out (creating an unbalanced quotes) in the insert command... OR a semi-colon which indicates the end of one statement and begins the next.

EDIT..

Then is it perhaps a type-o between insert column

mutradifat

and VALUE field of

mymuradifat

one has a "muTr"... the other "mur"...

I would definitely change it over to parameterized queries, such as

```
 DBInsert.CommandText = "Insert Into data " _
             & "(word, pronounce, language, siga, mufradat, english, murakabat) " _
             & "Values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";

DBInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "myWord", myword );
DBInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "myPronounce", mypronounce );
DBInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "myLanguage", mylanguage );
DBInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "mySiga", mysiga );
DBInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "myUradifat", mymuradifat );
DBInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "myEnglish", myenglish );
DBInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "myMurakbat", mymurakbat );
```

In addition, after a sample insert, you can probably get rid of the

YourVariable = Replace( YourVariable, "'", "''")

instances since the parametrization won't have the issue of mis-matched quotes in the command itself.

Comment: thanks for info but iam using this code just for my own use, secondly there is no single quote or any semi-colon. i replace single quotes with ""

Comment: spellings dose not matters because this is exact column name in database

Comment: @user934820, that may be true, but if your variable name was mis-typed as EXPECTED, it wouldn't find the value and corrupt your insert command itself.  I would edit your question and post the actual error message.  In addition, show what the values are for each of your respective variables... that may trigger something from someone.

Comment: @user934820, see revision working the insert with parameterized values

Comment: thank you guys problem is solved just by changing the column name "language" to "mylanguage".

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell what the problem is without knowing what error you received.  At first glance the statement looks correct.  All I see is the variables for mymuradifat and mymurakbat do not match the spelling of mutradifat and murakabat which is no issue if that is what you named them.  Are you sure the names are correct.  What is the error?

Comment: "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." iam getting this errror

Answer (score 0):

```
DBInsert.CommandText = "Insert Into data " _
             & "(word,pronounce,language,siga,mufradat,english,murakabat) " _
```

I dont think those 2 underlines "_" should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosing SQL like this can be tricky. The best way to start would be breakpoint the lines where it creates the insert command, then grab the SQL that is created and paste it into management studio (or anywhere you can view the text properly).

You might find that an extra ' is being added or a typo as suggested above.  Recheck all your column names and examine the SQL you are going to execute carefully. Also check that you dont have any characters like -- which sql could consider as a comment. And that SQL can store the characters you are passing in.

Aside from this I strongly recommend using stored procedures and parameters, even if this is only for your own personal use it doesn't hurt to use good practice and its a good habit to build.